# Node Orm2 transaction plugin

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, node-orm2

I'm seeming to have issues with how to use the transaction plugin (with postgresql) with node orm2. I think I am misunderstanding how transactions work with async function calls. Here is an example of my code:

```
function(row){
  db.transaction(function(err, txn){
    if(err){ return console.log(err) };       
    row.property = 'foo';

    row.save(function(err){
      if(err){ return console.log(err) };
      console.log("saved");
    });

    txn.commit(function(err){
      if(err){ return console.log(err) };
      console.log("committed");
    });
  });
```

When I run this piece of code, occasionally I will see console.log output this:

```
"committed"
"saved"
```

Which is the reverse order of what I expected. And the changes I made to row is not saved to the database. It looks like there is some issue with async function calls here, but I was just following the documentation from the node orm2 transaction plugin.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
function(row){
  db.transaction(function(err, txn){
  if(err){ return console.log(err) };       
  row.property = 'foo';

  row.save(function(err){
    if(err){ return console.log(err) };
    console.log("saved");
    txn.commit(function(err){
      if(err){ return console.log(err) };
      console.log("committed");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if you do the commiting of the transaction in the callback, it will work, and also if the row.save does return an error, you can simply return without running commit, and the chain won't be commited. I tried it for nested create statements, had a whole bunch which are dependent of each other. As long as you don't commit, none of the statements will be commited. 

Thanks for this, the documentation was a bit unclear.